# MediaPlayer Issue (t's not working only in oreo (8.0,8.1) android version)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
public void Play(string pathToAudioFile)
{
    if (_mediaPlayer != null)
    {
        _mediaPlayer.Completion -= MediaPlayer_Completion;
        _mediaPlayer.Stop();
    }

    if (pathToAudioFile != null)
    {
        if (_mediaPlayer == null)
        {
            _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            _mediaPlayer.Prepared += (sender, args) =>
            {
                _mediaPlayer.Start();
                _mediaPlayer.Completion += MediaPlayer_Completion;
            };//it's not firing in oreo 
        }

        _mediaPlayer.Reset();
        //_mediaPlayer.SetVolume (1.0f, 1.0f);

        _mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(pathToAudioFile);
        _mediaPlayer.PrepareAsync();
    }
}
```

this is my code it's not working in oreo versions,other versions it's working fine ,please help me in this case how to fix,thank you.

Comment: Kindly add your error logs, it will be helpful.

Comment: What exactly is "not working in oreo" mean? Also review and add the `logcat` messages to your question, you can filter on `MediaPlayerNative`, `MediaPlayer`, `MediaHTTPConnection`

Comment: 05-23 21:16:26.630 E/MediaPlayerNative(23791): error (-38, 0)
05-23 21:16:26.639 V/MediaPlayer(23791): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
05-23 21:16:26.639 V/MediaPlayer(23791): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
05-23 21:16:26.640 I/MediaPlayer(23791): setDataSource:/data/user/0/com.ancenergy.ebs/files/4003.wav
05-23 21:16:26.668 E/MediaPlayerNative(23791): error (1, -2147483648)
05-23 21:16:26.710 E/MediaPlayer(23791): Error (1,-2147483648)

Comment: Please check the above comment i mentioned log cat,the issue is Prepared is not firing

Comment: @Vinodkumar `Error (1,-2147483648)` typically means that the native C/C++ library for MediaPlayer is failing to decode the media, i.e. that media format is not supported on that device. What media format are you trying to play?

Comment: @ SushiHangover thank you, am trying to play .wav format media file